# "WFLYCTL0063: The composite operation has been cancelled"

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a JBoss 7.X server running on a VMware VM.

I cloned the VM to have two identical environments (Test and Dev).
However, in the cloned VM, I have a WAR file, and its deployment fails on the JBoss server with the message in the log "WFLYCTL0063: The composite operation has been cancelled."

I kindly request your support in identifying potential solutions to successfully deploy the mentioned WAR file. I am available to provide any additional information if needed.

VM is a windows server 2019 Data center.

Deploy war on jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\deployments
but deployment FAILED
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3QCj.png)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? You might need to set the `jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout` to something higher if the deployment is large.